# How to check if Datetime matches each other and show appropriate value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, datetime, foreach

Basically I just want to check if there any datetime value from database that matches to the **datetime reference**. If data found(matched), then I want to show **clock in** value from database.

First value is the datetime reference:

```
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
```

Second value is from database which contain **attendance dates**

```
2017-11-01, 2017-11-02, 2017-11-05,2017-11-06, 2017-11-07, 2017-11-08, 2017-
11-09, 2017-11-12 2017-11-13, 2017-11-14, 2017-11-15, 2017-11-16, 2017-11-19

$attend=$attend_list->dates;
```

So far I've been trying this code, but Im clueless. Please help.

```
$month="11";
$year="2017";
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);?>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Dates: </td>
    <?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++)
    {
        $date_list=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$month/$i"));
        echo"<td>".$date_list."</td>";
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Clock in : </td>
    <?php 

    for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++){

        $dates=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$month/$i"));

        foreach($attend_list as $value){
        $attend=$value->dates;  

        if($dates==$attend){ //if the data matched show value
            echo "<td>".$value->clock_in."</td>"; //???value that I was looking for
        }else{
            echo "<td>NULL</td>";
        }   
        }
    }?>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

That code was actually running but gave me undesired result. Where was I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the value of  the variable `$bulan` that is missing in your question.

Comment: @AaronK.Im sorry...I've updated my code